# Copy data from one table into other table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
INSERT INTO delete_subscriber (SubID,RandomCode,Email,FirstName,LastName,CreateDate,UpdateDate) 
SELECT subscriber.* 
FROM subscriber, list_sub 
WHERE ListID=? AND list_sub.SubID=subscriber.SubID;
```

I use a select statement to get all the record and store it into the other database, the problem is , there are more column in the delete_subscriber, that means there has a column e.g. delete date, delete person that is not in subscriber table.

How can I add them in one sql statement ? Or i have to use another statement?
But if i try the latter method, the problem is delete date, delete person are not null, I can not insert the partial record using the 1st statement

```
INSERT INTO delete_subscriber (SubID,RandomCode,Email,FirstName,LastName,CreateDate,UpdateDate,DeleteDate,DeletePerson) 
SELECT s.SubID,s.RandomCode,s.Email,s.FirstName,s.LastName,s.CreateDate,s.UpdateDate,NOW(),?
FROM subscriber s , list_sub
WHERE list_sub.ListID=? AND list_sub.SubID=s.SubID;
```

I can run it on sql but not php pdo? i found it not doing transaction

Comment: Can delete date be autocomputed (wrt system date) or is it dependent on another table?

Comment: In that case, do the following : remove * from the select query and specify all the columns; add the new columns you want as constants in that select statement eg. now() as delete_date

Comment: Sorry but i may get confused, how about the name?  i have edit the post and add the test sql, but not working.

Comment: The list (SubID,RandomCode,Email,FirstName,LastName,CreateDate,UpdateDate) needs to include all your selected columns now. eg. it should be something like (SubID,RandomCode,Email,FirstName,LastName,CreateDate,UpdateDate, DeleteDate,Userid)

Comment: good . Your answer is correct

Comment: Cool. I'll post it as an answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your insert statement to

```
INSERT INTO delete_subscriber        
(SubID,RandomCode,Email,FirstName,LastName,
CreateDate,UpdateDate,DeleteDate,DeletingPerson) 
 SELECT     s.SubID,s.RandomCode,s.Email,s.FirstName,s.LastName,
s.CreateDate,s.UpdateDate,NOW(),?
 FROM subscriber s , list_sub
WHERE list_sub.ListID=? AND list_sub.SubID=s.SubID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Alter delete_subscriber table set delete date, delete person default null before insert.and after populating data from select query modify again them as previous, not null.

Comment: Sorry i don't know why my editor in stackoverflow disappered, do you think this code to insert is ok? This is the two sql statement

Comment: why you are populating from script>? you can execute query directly in database

Comment: Then the 2nd statement is not using insert but alter as well? since i am insert data to exist record , and how can i refer them to the 1st id one by one?